# YITH WooCommerce Ajax Price Filter

Tags: ajax, filter, slider, woocommerce

Please I need to know where is the price slider filter I can not find it in the widgets!.
Do I have to add all filter options I need as attributes to the product? even category and price? This will make me make double entry for each product for category and price options for example. Please let me know as I am having difficulty finding support for the plugin although it’s very useful and free!. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From this site you will find that.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/